# Name the column of data frame and set as factor at the same time

Tags: r, matrix, dataframe

I need your help to simplify the following code.
I need to name the columns of matrix and format each of it as factor. 
How can I do that for 100 columns without doing it one by one.

```
z <- matrix(sample(seq(3),n*p,replace=TRUE),nrow=n)
train.data <- data.frame(x1=factor(z[,1],x2=factor(z[,2],....,x100=factor(z[,52]))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one option

```
setNames(data.frame(lapply(split(z, col(z)), factor)), paste0("x", 1:p))
```

or use magrittr piping syntax

```
library(magrittr)
split(z, col(z)) %>% 
    lapply(factor) %>% 
    data.frame %>% 
    setNames(paste0("x", 1:p))
```